# CGFloat in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, cgfloat

After updating Swift to 2.0 I need to fix my code. Automatic correction doesn't work.

```
func getValueForKey(key: String) -> CGFloat {
        var inch = ""
        if screenSize.height == 480 {
            // iPhone 4, 4s and below
            inch = "3.5"
        } else if screenSize.height == 568 {
            // iPhone 5, 5s
            inch = "4"
        } else if screenSize.width == 375 {
            // iPhone 6
            inch = "4.7"
        } else if screenSize.width == 414 {
            // iPhone 6+
            inch = "5.5"
        } else if screenSize.width == 768 {
            // iPad
            inch = "5.5+"
        }
        let result = values["\(key)\(inch)"]!
        //        println("\(key) - \(result)")
        return result
    }
```

[image]

I have changed it.
But nothing happens and it appears again!

How to fix it?

Comment: hm..it works for me....it actually declared in CoreGraphics, try to restart your xcode

Comment: Thx) import UIKit helped  ... my fail ( But it worked before ... strange things happening :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on why importing `UIKit` fixes this problem:

The `CGFloat` struct is part of the `CoreGraphics` framework.  `UIKit` by default imports `Foundation` which imports `CoreGraphics`.

If you weren't using `UIKit` or were on a platform that doesn't have the `UIKit` framework (such as Linux), Importing the `Foundation` module will import `CoreGraphics`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was absence of library UIKit.

```
import UIKit
```

This code before class has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

seems enough using:
 import CoreGraphics.